# How to `docker-compose run` outside the working directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, working-directory

Suppose I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
    
WORKDIR /src/mydir
```

Now, suppose I want to run docker-compose from the `src/` folder as opposed to `src/mydir` as happens by default.

I tried the following:

`docker-compose run my_container ../ my-task`

However the above failed.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: The `/src` directory is inside the image (and apparently nothing else is?); you'd generally run `docker-compose` from the host.  Can you provide a clearer explanation of what effect you're looking for, and a [mcve] demonstrating the setup?

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze,

I managed to get it working with the following:

`docker-compose run my_container /bin/sh -c "cd .. && python -m unittest discover my_container -v"`

I can use the `/bin/sh` command to `cd ..` and then run the command I needed from there

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `--workdir` (or `-w`) option of the `docker-compose run` command.

See the official documentation of the command here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

For instance, given your above example:

```
docker-compose run my_container -w /src my-task
```